# Is there possible to return vuejs component in mounted?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm trying to return Vuejs custom component in mounted but not able to to success. Just html push return working fine.

```
<script>
import DatatabelCell from "./DatatableCell";
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            rows: [],
            columns: [
                { name: "Name", field: "name" },
                { name: "ID", field: "id" },
                { name: "Type", field: "brewery_type" },
                { name: "State", field: "state" },
            ],
        };
    },
    mounted() {
        let filterData = [];
        const columns = this.columns;
        this.tableData.forEach(function (row) {
            const filteredByColumn = [];
            columns.forEach((column) => {
                filteredByColumn.push(<DatatabelCell :value="[row[column.field]]"/>);
                return column;
            });
            filterData.push(filteredByColumn);
        });
    },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Why not use a `v-for` in your template?

Answer (score 0):

I'd create the `filteredData` array within the `computed` property and use the `html` template using a `v-for` loop. Something along these lines.

```
<script>
import DatatabelCell from "./DatatableCell";
export default {
     data() {
          return {
                rows: [],
                columns: [
                     { name: "Name", field: "name" },
                     { name: "ID", field: "id" },
                     { name: "Type", field: "brewery_type" },
                     { name: "State", field: "state" },
                ],
          };
     },

     computed: {
        filteredData: function () {
            const filteredByColumn = [];

            this.tableData.forEach(row => {
                this.columns.forEach(column => {
                    filteredByColumn.push([row[column.field]]);
                });
            });

            return filteredByColumn;
        }
    }
};
</script>
```

```
<template>
<div v-for="(cell, i) in filteredData" :key="i">
    <DatatabelCell :value="cell">
</div>
</template>
```